# Regexp в mysql

Tags: регулярные-выражения, mysql

Для замены текста в wordpress через БД пользуюсь командой:

```
update wp_posts set post content =
replace(post_content, 'что меняю', 'на
что меняю');
```

Но теперь мне понадобилось во всех постах сменить такой отрезок текста:

```
<img src="http://mysite.com/profnews/**biblio-globus-avtobusom-k-moriu**/0.jpg" style="cursor: default; float: left; margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;"/>
```

на

`''`

а точнее стереть, при том что выделенный шрифтом код - может быть разными папками.

Так вот вопрос насчет регулярок в mysql -  как можно автоматизировать замену через regexp.

Пробовал так:

```
update wp_posts set post_content =
replace(post_content, regexp '<img
id="photoset-main-image-1803124"
style="width: auto; min-width: 500px;"
src="http://mysite.com/images/+/main.jpg"
alt="image" />','');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REGEXP_REPLACE в MySQL нет, недавно сам сталкивался с данной задачей
http://chesser.ru/blog/how_to_regexp_replace_text_field_in_mysql/